# android.view.InflateException , Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I know this is a repeat, but cant find a solution. This is my Map XML file

activity_map

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.test.healthapp.MapActivity" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MapActivity (on setContentView) snippet where the error occurs:
MapActivity is extending FragmentActivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
```

And my Logcat

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.ather.healthapp, PID: 10185
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ather.healthapp/com.example.ather.healthapp.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
                                                                             at com.example.ather.healthapp.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:97)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                             at com.example.ather.healthapp.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:97) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:466)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2379)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:376)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                             at com.example.ather.healthapp.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:97) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

Your help will be much appreciated. 
I have tried to change layout of activity_map to LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and Framelayout, but nothing works. Tried adding android:name or class to the fragment in line 15 of activity_map.

Comment: Your second fragment tag hasn't a fragment class defined. Hence the null pointer exception.

Comment: Should I add 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" in the second fragment?

Comment: No, at least you want to show two maps. If you don't want a Fragment there, then just get rid that tag. If you want to dynamically add another fragment, then you use add your fragment using the FragmentManager by code and not statically in the layout.

Comment: Yeah, solved. Added android:name = "com.example.....FragmentClass" in the second fragment. Thanks alot

Comment: No problem bro =). Then I'll add this as an aswer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare these in your Manifest.xml file?

Declare it within the `<application>` element and your code should work.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And also

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your second fragment tag hasn't a fragment class defined, then a NullPointerException is launched because the Android framework expects a class to be loaded there. You should get rid of that tag (if you don't need it), add a fragment class to be loaded or use a dynamic fragment loading approach if you want to add dynamically a fragment there. Check this [guide of the official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout).